# Clicking on a list item in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get a Python script to click on a webpage element that's part of a scrollable list.  I don't see any way to reference the element that's unique.  What am I missing?
I've included a screenshot of the page as well as the relevant DOM code.

[image]

[image]

I haven't tried anything, as I don't know how to reference the first element in the list.  It would be nice to also be able to reference the second element and perhaps the third.  However, referencing the first is the most important at this time.

Comment: can you copy the element with id="search-results" and include in the question? You can get selector or xpath by `Right-click` -> `copy` -> `copy selector` or `copy xpath`

Comment: selector for the element being pointed at seems to be `#search-results > .row > addGroupBtn > button > i`. I could be wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using the full XPATH.  However, I feel that's risky and might fail with any change to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the CSS selector and grab 2 of the class of the element & it's parent.

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".addGroupBtn.fa.fa-plus")[0].click()
```